# Docker compose up [ecs context] with private repo

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

Trying to upload compose.yml to aws with docker-compose [ecs context];
Have my private repositories in https://hub.docker.com/.

1. Created ecs context, started to use it (docker context use)
2. Executed `docker login` -> login succeeded
3. Executed `docker compose up`

It fails and returns the error

> ServerService TaskFailedToStart: CannotPullContainerError: inspect image has been retried 1 time(s): failed to resolve ref "docker.io/myrepo/server:latest": pull access denied, the repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization...'

How should I get access to this 'docker ecs compose' tool? Is it related somehow to aws credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `x-aws-pull_credentials` key, which points to a secretsmanager ARN, as described here: https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/#private-docker-images

Create a secret using `docker secret`:

```sh
echo '{"username":"joe","password":"hunter2"}' | docker secret create myToken -
arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-3:12345:secret:myToken
```

In your compose file:

```yaml
services:
  worker:
    image: mycompany/privateimage
    x-aws-pull_credentials: "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-3:12345:secret:myToken"
```